In my Blazor server side app with windows authentication, I want to force that each time my page is opened, the login page appears. Is that possible?
In my Blazor server side app I have set windows configuration. If a user opens my page the first time, the login dialog box appears and the user has to log in. But the next time, I think it is cached by the browser, and the user enters the page without login. Of course this has some advantages, but for some reasons I want to force that the login dialog box comes everytime. Can I do that from my app, without clearing the cache of the browser?

You could have a Scoped service with a bool FreshlyLoggedIn variable that you set to true only in the login page.  Then in your Layout page, check that variable and if it's not set, force a logout and redirect to login.

@Bennyboy1973 Thank you for the suggestion, but: The login page is a standard login page of the browser, its out of my control. How can I set this variable to true in this case?

That's not true.  The standard login page in Blazor is fully within your control.
